# Get GPS Coordinates on mouse tap/click on ArcGIS Esri Map in Windows Runtime Apps (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

How to get the GPS coordinates (longitude, latitude) of the clicked/tapped point in ArcGIS Esri map?

I tried `MapViewTapped` event like:

```
private void myMapView_MapViewTapped(object sender, MapViewInputEventAtgs e)
{
  var x = e.Position.X; //e.Location.X;
  var y = e.Position.Y; //e.Location.Y;
}
```

Both it gives large unexpected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the MapViewInputEventArgs.Position property - this gives screen coordinates - see the [sample code for Show Mouse Coordinates](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/sample-code/ShowMouseCoordinates/). Use the Location property to get map coordinates, as also shown in the sample.

Worth noting that it's very likely that your Map is using the [Web Mercator coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) - e.g. if you have created a MapView using the default Esri basemaps. If so, the map coordinates will be reported in Meters, approximately in the range -20,000,000 to +20,000,000.

The coordinate system WGS84 gives latitude and longitude in degrees, and is used by GPS systems. To convert a point from another coordinate system (e.g. the SpatialReference of your MapView, if different to that), you can 'project' the point - use the Project method on the GeometryEngine class, and pass in a MapPoint and the SpatialReference you want, e.g.

```
MapPoint projectedPoint = GeometryEngine.Project(e.Location, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
```

See the [Project Coordinate](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/sample-code/ProjectCoordinate/) sample that demonstrates that.